# ¿Cómo hago para dar la función de agregar notas al botón usando isotope?

Tags: javascript, html5, bootstrap, css3

Pues eso, estoy haciendo un ejercicio que me han mandado de crear y borrar notas y necesito que al clicar el botón que agrega las notas me agregue una nueva nota, lo que no sé es cómo sería esa función con isotope, ¿alguna idea?

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Google Keep Layout</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css">


      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">


</head>

<body>
  <div class="notes"></div>

<button class="big-add show-add-note"><i class="material-icons">add</i></button>

  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.isotope/2.2.1/isotope.pkgd.js'></script>

    <script src="js/index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
//(function() {
  var makeNote;

  makeNote = function() {
    var height;
    height = parseInt(100 + Math.random() * 500, 10);
    return '<div class="note"><div class="note-inner" style="height: ' + height + 'px"></div></div>';
  };

  $(function() {
    var $note, $notes, i, x;
    $notes = $(".notes");
    for (x = i = 0; i <= 10; x = ++i) {
      $note = $(makeNote());
      $notes.append($note);
    }
    return $('.notes').isotope({
      itemSelector: '.note',
      layoutMode: 'masonry'
    });
  });

//}).call(this);
```

**Captura**
[image: Captura del ejercicio]

Comment: Según la documentación se agrega mediante: `.append(elem).isotope('appended', elem)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te dejo un ejemplo: el código esta un poco comentado, esta librería es muy flexible, me impresiono. para agregar elementos `.isotope( 'appended', $items, callback )`
y para eliminar elementos `.isotope( 'remove', $items, callback )`

```js
var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({ //obeteniendo el control de la regilla
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  masonry: {
    columnWidth: 80
  }
});

$('.big-add').on('click', function() { //agregar elemento por cada click
  var $items = getItemElement();
  $grid.append($items).isotope('appended', $items);
});

   $grid.on( 'dblclick', '.grid-item', function() {
  // elimina un elemento seleccionado con doble click
  $grid.isotope( 'remove', this )
.isotope('layout');
});


function getItemElement() {
  var $item = $('<div class="grid-item"><div contenteditable> </div></div>'); //crear un elemento
  return $item;
}
```

```css
.grid {
  max-width: 1200px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 80px;
}

.grid:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  margin: 5px;
}

.grid-item {
  float: left;
  width: 130px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #Ea8;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  border-color: hsla(10, 10%, 0%, 0.7);
  margin: 1px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css">
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.isotope/2.2.1/isotope.pkgd.js'></script>
<button class="big-add show-add-note"><i class="material-icons">add</i>
</button>

<div class="grid">

</div>
```

**nota:** con un solo click en cada caja se puede insertar la nota(escribiendo).

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta compañero! se ve que el tema de isotope es potente!